# How to get the data in input field

Tags: sql, asp.net, razor

I am unable to get the data in the text field if it is already present in the Database.

Problem: I want to Put the data in the text fields of input tag when the page loads. So, that it could be easy to edit the specific field.

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Edit Record | Student Registration System ";
    var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
    var info = UrlData[0];

    Validation.RequireField("Student_Reg_No", "Student Reg No is required.");

    if (info.IsEmpty())
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/default");
    }

    else if (IsPost) {
        var value = Request.Form["value"];
        var Student_Reg_No = Request.Form["Student_Reg_No"];

        if (Validation.IsValid()){
            // try{
            var db = Database.Open("site_data");
            var updateCommand = "Update site_data_table set Student_Reg_No =@0, Student_Name=@1 where Student_Reg_No=@0";
            db.Execute(updateCommand, Student_Reg_No);

            Response.Redirect(@Href("~/default"));
            @Href("~/ edit.cshtml   ", @value);
        }

    }
    else {

        var db1 = Database.Open("site_data");
        var row = db1.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM site_data_table WHERE  Id =@0", info);

        var value = row.id;
        var Student_Reg_No = row.Student_Reg_No;
        <textarea>hi aasdasd</textarea>
    }
}
```

From here The HTML part is starting

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <input type="text" name="value" value="@Request.Form["value"]"
        <tr>
            <label for="Student_Reg_No">Student Reg No:</label> </br>
            <input type="text" name="Student_Reg_No" value="@Request.Form["Student_Reg_No"]" />
            <span class="error"> @Html.ValidationMessage("Student_Reg_No")   </span>
        </tr></br>

        <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add Movie" /></p>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Wondering why PHP is tagged..

Comment: Because the syntax is almost like the php

Comment: LOL *Because the syntax is almost like the php* are you serious ?

Comment: I think so ... hahaha

Comment: @AhsanUlHaq I think it would be better if you [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to improve your chances of getting an answer!

Comment: @AhsanUlHaq, Your question is not in a format, please do some separation between your view and code, so, other can at least understand that

Comment: @Div Code length decreases for better understanding

Comment: @AhsanUlHaq So, your problem is `Student_Reg_No` value not set on page refresh

Comment: Yes and on pageload too

Comment: You can save it in `ViewBag` and give that value to the `input type="text"`

Comment: I am not using MVC

Comment: What you're using ?

Comment: I am doing it with razor pages

Comment: And what you are using as code behind ?